# How to restart python program running in windows command line from point of error?

Tags: python, windows, try-catch, wrapper

I have a scraper that runs on windows command line. The scraper shuts down after about two days of running (due to an unspecified error). How can I implement some code to have the program run again when an error is encountered? Also, how can I make it run from the point it just stopped?

Comment: Perhaps create a scheduled task for to run the scraper at an interval instead of leaving the scraper running forever?

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can make it run from where it stops is that if you actually store the data somewhere else, if something basic; you can use simply a text file to write your scraping output. For the part where it gets an `unspecified` error; if the error stops the script you can have your whole code in a `while` loop.

```
while True:
    last_scraped_point = "You should update this in your script"
    try:
        # Start with using the last_scraped_point
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

This would simply keep restarting the script from where it stopped working

Comment: Thank you so much, as a side note the output is in an excel file saved to the desktop! I will try this out.